why in calling a function by GCC convention , the passed parameters are stored in a reversed order in the stack

Can you help me answer this question. I have tried to figure this out by myself but didn't succeed. Is it because we don't know the amount of memory the function will use ?

"reverse" is a question of the perspective. If you look at the stack from bottom to top it can be called reverse, but if you look at the address in memory, then everything looks "normal".
